# Can I Repot a Jade tree in December?

Tags: trees, bonsai, repotting, jade

Would it harm my Jade tree if I repot it in December? I don't need to prune its roots, but I want to move it to a smaller pot and turn it into a [mame bonsai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonsai#Size_classifications) instead.

Can I do it now or maybe I should wait till Spring?

UPDATE: I went ahead and repotted it. This is the repotted version of the tree.

[image]

Comment: Some details about the environment in which you are keeping the jade might be helpful (e.g. indoors, outdoors in Manila).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it would really harm, but the best time to [repot bonsai](https://www.bonsaiempire.com/basics/bonsai-care/repotting) is early spring. The reason is that in early springtime the plants are still in dormancy, but will start growing soon again. So it will grow new roots easily. Important is that you don't have frost during this regrowth period, because the new growth is very sensitive to this.

Of course it is not clear what your climate is, if you have no frost period that wouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: The plant is indoor, so it's always above 20˚C / 68˚F. It could get very cold here during the winter (like -20C) but that's outside, the plants are always inside

Comment: Even without freezing temperature, your plant might still get into dormancy (because of reduction of light length and intensity). Advice is to wait to the moment just before the growth period (spring).

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that by "Jade tree" you mean a Crassula - if not, please let me know and I'll delete this answer.

I'd repot it now. I've grown jade plants for decades and haven't given time for repotting much thought - done it winter or summer with no ill effects. Just keep the plant out of direct sunlight for a week or so.

Comment: Yes, I actually repotted it and I've noticed that the roots were sort of rotting so I'd be careful with the watering process. It's in a mame bonsai pot right now, it's a smaller one so I'd try to water it every 4+ days. They don't require much water anyway